# Graceful shutdown kafka consumer

Tags: hazelcast, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 3.1.6 and hazelcast 3.7.4.

When shutting down my application, it seems like hazelcast is shutting down before my kafka consumer.

Thus leading to errors

```
nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
```

and

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException: null
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeTriggerWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:422)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:245)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:208)
```

My consumer is configured with a RetryTemplate.

```
org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor   Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483547 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry]
```

Can someone help me to graceful shutdown by making hazelcast waiting for the kafka container to stop ?

Thanks

**Edit**

Both KafkaContainer and HazelcastInstance are beans handled by spring.

HazelcastInstance is created manually (not using default springboot autoconfiguration) :

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    LOGGER.info("Closing Hazelcast");
    Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    LOGGER.debug("Configuring Hazelcast");
    Config config = new Config();
    ...
```

And Kafka Container :

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Key, Value> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Key, Value> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs()));
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.RECORD);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I'm running the application replicated 3 times. All 3 replicas has been shutdown at the same moment.

Here is the shutdown logs history for 1 replica :

1) 18:14:54.427 "ContextClosedEvent" spring event has been catched by a component and logged

2) 18:14:54.441 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException: null

3) 18:14:55.951 com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!

4) Repeat 3) 19 times from 18:14:55.951 to 18:15:23.103

5) 18:15:24.441 Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483547 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry]

6) 18:15:24.537 Closing Hazelcast

Comment: Are both Kafka consumer and Hazelcast Spring beans? Both are destroyed during Spring context shutdown?

Comment: just edited my question. Just noticed i'm using a @PreDestroy to close Hazelcast which is not done in HazelcastAutoConfiguration from springboot.
Could it be caused by that ? I should not destory it ? Inspired by https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-hazelcast/blob/5a867c902acbf4b7ebc19b84a0f2601fdce4866b/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/CacheConfiguration.java#L32

Comment: You should definitely shutdown Hazelcast at some point while shutting down the application, otherwise Hazelcast threads will remain alive.

Comment: @JohnD did you find any solution for this? because I'm facing the same issue. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Clover no, I did not find any solution, we ended up by removing the DB dependency and using compacted topic

Answer (score 2):

This might the wrong thread for client based setup but for embed based setup, Here that worked for me.

set this property to false,

```
hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled = false
```

> hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled = true
>
> Enable Hazelcast shutdownhook thread. When this is enabled, this
> thread terminates the Hazelcast instance without waiting to shutdown
> gracefully.

by default, this is to set to true. for more [info](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#system-properties)

Helped me not to forcefully kill hazelcast but i had to call `hazelcastInstance.shutdown()`
explicitly

Answer (score 1):

If Kafka consumer bean is not directly depending on Hazelcast bean, then you can define an order between beans (during both initialization and destruction time), using `depends-on` attribute of bean definitions. Like;

```
<bean id="kafka-consumer" class="KafkaConsumerClassName" depends-on="hazelcast"/>
<bean id="hazelcast" class="HazelcastInstance" />
```

In this case, Hazelcast bean will be created & initialized *before* Kafka consumer bean and it will be destroyed *after* Kafka consumer bean.

See [Using depends-on](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-dependson) section in Spring reference manual.

Comment: After further reading the log.
The log "Closing Hazelcast" is happening after the consumer errors. I don't know where the "Hazelcast instance is not active!" come from in that case.

Comment: It may be coming from another shutting down Hazelcast node. Are you shutting down multiple instances of the application? How many Hazelcast nodes are in the cluster?

Comment: The application is running hazelcast lib as client/server. The application was running with 3 replicas, they were all shutdown at the same time.